# list.add not working with ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I am trying to add integers from a file into an ArrayList and list.add doesn't want to work.  I've only tried about a thousand different ways to write this code.  The `list.add(s.next());` line gives an error in Eclipse,

> `The method add(Integer) in the type List<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (String).`

Sounds like I am somehow trying to do something with an integer that can only be done with a string, but I need them to remain integers and if I hadn't been searching, studying and cramming my head with Java for the last 5 days straight I could probably understand what it means.

I can get it to work with a regular array just fine, but my ArrayList collection is a real pain and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyCollection {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

        //---- ArrayList 'list'
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/emissary/Desktop/workspace/stuff/src/numbers.txt"));

        while   (s.hasNext())   {
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();

        Collections.sort(list);
        for (Integer integer : list){
            System.out.printf("%s, ", integer);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Scanner#next()` returns a String, you want `Scanner#nextInt()`. This will also require some more specific file handling (`hasNextInt()`) and skipping new lines depending on your format of your txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a `String` to a list of `Integer`s.

`s.next()` returns the next token as a string, which cannot be added to a list of integer obviously.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, that did the trick! I think I have had my head buried in the books for too long and just got burned out. Thanks for helping me catch the obvious!

Answer (score 3):

`s.next()` refers to a method that returns a `String` type. Since Java is strongly typed, an integer or `int` type must be returned from the user. `s.nextInt()` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, that did the trick!  

I think I have had my head buried in the books for too long and just got burned out.  Thanks for helping me catch the obvious!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //---- ArrayList 'list'
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/emissary/Desktop/workspace/stuff/src/numbers.txt"));

    while   (s.hasNextInt())   {
        list.add(s.nextInt());
    }
    s.close();

    Collections.sort(list);
    for (Integer integer : list){
        System.out.printf("%s, ", integer);
    }
```

s.hasNextInt() checks if there is an integer in the next data from scanner. And to add integer into a list of integer you must use nextInt that return an integer but not a string
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Thanks for all the help, that did the trick!  

I think I have had my head buried in the books for too long and just got burned out.  Thanks for helping me catch the obvious!